# Neo4j import csv from command line but get an error "Input error: Expected '--nodes' to have at least 1 item, but had 0"

Tags: csv, neo4j

so I try to follow the [document](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/re03.html) to import nodes and relations all at once using command line.

```
./neo4j-import --into /Users/Zhen/desktop/Courses/Bigdata/stackexchange/data \
--nodes post2.csv --relationships post_relation.csv --delimiter ";" --array-delimiter "|"
```

However, I got the following error message. Can anyone give me a hint of how to fix it? Thanks!

```
Input error: Expected '--nodes' to have at least 1 item, but had 0 ([])
Caused by:Expected '--nodes' to have at least 1 item, but had 0 ([])
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected '--nodes' to have at least 1 item, but had 0 ([])
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.Validators$4.validate(Validators.java:114)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.Validators$4.validate(Validators.java:108)
at org.neo4j.helpers.Args.validated(Args.java:594)
at org.neo4j.helpers.Args.interpretOptionsWithMetadata(Args.java:562)
at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool$8.apply(ImportTool.java:721)
at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool$8.apply(ImportTool.java:717)
at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool.main(ImportTool.java:315)
at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool.main(ImportTool.java:279)
```

my data is as follows:
$head post2.csv

```
postID:ID;CreationDate;Tags;ViewCount;FavoriteCount;:LABEL
5;2014-05-13T23:58:30.457;[machine-learning];240;1;1
7;2014-05-14T00:11:06.457;[education];245;1;1
9;2014-05-14T00:36:31.077;;;;2
10;2014-05-14T00:53:43.273;;;;2
14;2014-05-14T01:25:59.677;[data-mining];619;2;1
15;2014-05-14T01:41:23.110;[databases];110;;1
16;2014-05-14T01:57:56.880;[machine-learning, libsvm];186;;1
```

$head post_relation.csv

```
:START_ID;:END_ID;:TYPE
9;5;post_relation
10;7;post_relation
21;19;post_relation
23;7;post_relation
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the correct path to `post2.csv` (and also to `post_relation.csv`). (Presumably, your CSV files are not in the neo4j `bin` directory.)